# "Tired" or "tired of"?

Tags: prepositions

That show is something I can never get tired **of** watching.

That show is something I can never get tired watching.

Are both the sentences grammatically correct? I've never really heard anyone use tired in similar contexts and leave out the **of**, so I was just wondering if the second sentence is okay too.

Answer (score 8):

From "I get tired watching ..." I understand that watching ... makes you tired, literally; that you tend to get tired when you're watching ....

From "I get tired of watching ..." I understand "tired" figuratively: that you lose patience with having to watch ..., that you don't want to watch ... any more. A similar expression for this is "I'm fed up with watching".

The distinction is set forth at https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tired.

Comment: Agreed. You can improve the answer with this link, showing the difference of definitions between "tired" and "tired of". https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tired